# IE8 in VirtualBox doesn't display CSS styles in Dev Tools

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, virtualbox, mamp

Running into an issue that has me pulling hair out!

I am buildling a site and started browser testing. The page displays properly (with the regular IE breaks) but for some reason, does not display the actual CSS in the IE8 dev tools. Site is locally hosted with MAMP and using VirtualBox to test with IE/PC.

- I've added the IP to the hosts file in IE8.
- I've fixed all validation errors
- Even threw it up on a server to see if it was a local issue

Running HTML5 doctype so maybe thats the issue? But pulled it from HTML5 Boilerplate so I'm under the impression everything is good there?

Not really sure what the issue is and its driving me crazy.

Site is hosted here: [www.enkshows-dev.com](http://enkshows-dev.com)

- p: enkshows-dev
- w: enkshows-dev

Also - IE8 doesn't render the CSS file in the 'CSS' tab, but the page layout is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, folks. I figured it out.

Looks like IE8 gets hung up on the css link for the H&FJ cloud typography production fonts.

As soon as that's removed, all works swell.